# Retrieve last inserted 10 rows in table

Tags: mysql

How can I retrieve the last 10 rows inserted into a table?

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from tableName ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: how can i retrieve through user id

Comment: I guess you want something like               
select * from tableName where user_id=10 ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use the below query, please ensure about the `primary-key` field

```
select * from tbl ORDER BY 'ID' DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions for `MySql`:

1. check the rowcount of your table and use limit

   ```
   select count(*) from tableName;
   select * from tableName limit rowcount-10,rowcount;
   ```
2. `PhpMyAdmin` displays the results using pagination. You can go to last pages to see last inserted records.