# Find last 10 records in MySQL without date condition

Tags: mysql

How can we retrieve the last 10 rows from a table? Suppose we don't have the date and any other incremental ID in the table, then how it is possible to find the last 10 records without giving date condition?

Comment: Do you mean to retrieve the last 10 inserted records?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183655/retrieve-last-inserted-10-rows-in-table?rq=1

Comment: In general, you can't.  If you have the need to know when a record were inserted or updated, then you should add a timestamp column  to the table.

Comment: then how this code is working,      order by 1 desc limit 10

Answer (score 3):

No you can't.There is no way to do it. Without an auto-incrementing ID column or a timestamp/date/datetime, there's no way for the database to know which records were inserted last.

We need to have a reference point to do this